# brace breaking different for struct and class in clang-format 3.7.0

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I encountered different brace breaking behavior in `clang-format` for `struct`s and `class`es.

The following example file illustrates it:

**test.cpp**

```
class TestClass
{
int member;
};

struct TestStruct
{
int member;
};
```

Running `clang-format` v3.7.0 with `BreakBeforeBraces: Linux` yields:

```
$ clang-format test.cpp -style="{BreakBeforeBraces: Linux}"
class TestClass
{
  int member;
};

struct TestStruct {
  int member;
};
```

However, `clang-format` v3.5.0 results in:

```
class TestClass
{
  int member;
};

struct TestStruct
{
  int member;
};
```

Is this intended behavior? I did not find any hint in the changelogs.
How could I fix this?

Comment: why is this tagged `clang`?

Comment: @Walter I added that tag since `clang-format` is a tool provided by `clang`; if you think that tag is inappropriate, I'll remove it

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be intended behavior, since it is still there almost 5 years later, in `clang-format` version 10.0.0.

However, starting with version 3.8.0, you can fine-tune the `BreakBeforeBraces` behavior by setting `BreakBeforeBraces: Custom`. When you do this, you can then set the `BraceWrapping` flags. In particular, there are separate flags `AfterClass` and `AfterStruct` - if you set both of these to true you should get back the behavior you had with version 3.5.0. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for details on this.